# Header Fragments without thymeleaf

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I want to take a `<head>` from another html page normally with thyme leaf 
you will do something like this

```
<head th:fragment = "common/header"></head>
```

and this to get it on another page

```
<head th:replace="common/header :: common-header"></head>
```

But this a Thymeleaf tag.  I want to do this without Thymeleaf.  How is that possible I am working with bootstrap and its static libraries.

Comment: are you using JSP?

Comment: no currently all my pages are html , but what i found out is that th:fragment  works only at run time it cannot be tested by just clicking the chrome icon on the html page, is that right?

Comment: `th:fragment` works at runtime, yes.  I haven't used it, but Thymol could be what you need.  http://www.thymoljs.org/static-imports.html